# Calculate probability $P(\text{min}\{X_1, \ldots , X_k\} = X_j )$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose the exponential random variables $X_1, \ldots X_k$ are independent, each with parameter $\lambda_i$, respectively. Calculate $P(\text{min}\{X_1, \ldots , X_k\} = X_j )$, for $j \leq k$.

I already know that $X=\text{min}\{X_1, \ldots , X_k\}$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$. However I do not know how to calculate a probability of a r.v. being equal to another r.v... I was thinking I could maybe evaluate the probabilities $P(X=x_j | X_j = x_j)$ for every $x_j\in(0,\infty)$, and integrate over the whole of $(0,\infty)$. Is this going to work? I would prefer some hints over a complete answer, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this going to work?

Not *quite*.  You don't want equality, but a comparator ($\leq, \geq$).

You want the probability that whatever value $X_j$ takes is not greater than the value for any other memeber of the series.

The event $X_j=\min\{X_1,..,X_k\}$ (where $1\leq j\leq k$) is the event that $\forall i\in\{1,..,k\}~(X_j\leqslant X_i)$, so (since it is certain that $X_j\leq X_j$) and by using the independence and identical distribution of the random variables:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_j{=}\min{\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^k)~&=~\mathsf P(\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq k, i\neq j}~(X_j\leq X_i))\\[2ex]&=~\int_0^\infty \mathsf P(\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq k, i\neq j}~X_i\geq x\mid X_j=x)f_X(x)~\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=~\int_0^1\left(\prod_{1\leq i\leq k,i\neq j}\mathsf P(X_i\geq x)\right)~f_X(x)~\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&=~\int_0^\infty \left(\mathsf P(X_i\geq x)\right)^{k-1}~f_X(x)~\mathrm d x \\[2ex]&=~\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))^{k-1}~f_X(x)~\mathrm d x\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: I thought those events could not be independent... For $X_j \leq X_i$ might imply that $X_j \leq X_l $ for some $l$...

Comment: Oh, thank you. Indeed, those events are codependent, @Castor .  However, we're making use of the fact that the *random variables* are independent.  So for any $i\neq j$, we have $\mathsf P(X_i\geq x\mid X_j=x)=\mathsf P(X_i\geq x)$. $\\~\\$Tweaked answer for clarity.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X_j$ is the minimum iff $X_j \le X_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: I thought those events could not be independent... For $X_j \leq X_i$ might imply that $X_j \leq X_l $ for some $l$...